# mongodb full text search: phrases with special character "-"

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search, special-characters

I got a problem with the mongodb fts.
I want to search for parts in Haskell types. So I got a field *type* that looks, for example, like this:

```
type : "[a] -> [b] -> [(a,b)]"
```

I can search for *"[a]"*, *"[b]"* and *"[(a,b)]"* and I'll get the right document, that contains the above field. But if I try to search for *"[a] -> [b]"*, I'll get nothing.

```
> db.mycollection.runCommand("text",{search : "\"[a] -> [b]\""})
{
"queryDebugString" : "a||||||[a] -> [b]",
"language" : "none",
"results" : [ ],
"stats" : {
    "nscanned" : 1,
    "nscannedObjects" : 0,
    "n" : 0,
    "nfound" : 0,
    "timeMicros" : 185
},
"ok" : 1
}
```

First I thought that I should escape the special characters in my query, but it makes no difference and the *queryDebugString* allways looks the same.

If I don't use the arrow and my entry looks like this,

```
type : [a] > [b] > [(a,b)]
```

everything is fine. I can search for *"[a]"*, *"[b]"*, *"[(a,b)]"* AND *"[a] > [b]"* and I'll allways get the right document.

So whats's wrong with the search I'm needing?
Is it a bug or a concept I don't understand?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `-` means that it's a negated search, but that shouldn't happen in phrase searches (enclosed by "). I would suggest you file a bug report at http://jira.mongodb.org as this seems a bug.